# Factory pattern returning same instance

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

Let's take an example "factory" class written in C#:

```
public class HasherFactory : IHasherFactory
{
    private readonly Sha1Hasher _sha1Hasher;
    private readonly Sha2Hasher _sha2Hasher;

    public HasherFactory(Sha1Hasher sha1Hasher, Sha2Hasher sha2Hasher)
    {
        _sha1Hasher = sha1Hasher;
        _sha2Hasher = sha2Hasher;
    }

    public IHasher CreateHasher(string hashAlgorithm)
    {
        switch (hashAlgorithm.ToLower())
        {
            case "sha1":
                return _sha1Hasher;
            case "sha2":
                return _sha2Hasher;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid hash algorithm", nameof(hashAlgorithm));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have here is the naming convention of this class. Factory suggests that each execution of CreateHasher will return a new instance, but it is not the case. What is the pattern used here called?

Comment: Get vs create? What is your question?

Comment: this is a singleton pattern. Its an anti-pattern much like the factory pattern.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu, you mean it's an anti-pattern that happens to look like a factory; or it's an anti-pattern in the same way that factory is an anti-pattern?

Comment: Its an anti-pattern in the same way factory is an anti-pattern. This is accomplished much more resiliently via Dependency Injection

Answer (score 2):

It's called a singleton pattern in the case where the same instance is always returned... This is the equivalent of two singletons--a doubleton?

I would use "Get" though (Which is the standard for singletons, as in GetInstance().  In this case it would be GetHasher("sha1")

Comment: The doubleton pattern is half as good as the singleton pattern, but the fourbleton pattern is only 1/4th as good.

Comment: I would not consider this an implementation of the singleton pattern as sha1Hasher and sha2Hasher are passed into the class. There is nothing in the above that indicates that multiple instances of them aren't being created throughout the application. I'm also not considering this an implementation of the factory pattern as nothing is being created.

Comment: That's why I called it a "Doubleton", but you are right, it's not a singleton.  Perhaps it would be better to call it a "Holder".  Still, as a holder, GetHasher or just Get() would be a better name.